# React.js "useEffect" infinitive loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a function which needs to update data table and gets values from an API using fetch. When the page uploads, data comes perfectly with useEffect but i want it to be uploaded when i delete or add item into the table which doesn't work right now as it goes into infinitive loop.

```
const [data,setData] = useState();


 useEffect(() => {
   
   PersonService.getAllPersonList()
   .then(res => {
     setData(res)
     console.log(res)
   }
 )
 }, [data]);
```

Comment: I assume your effect is used when data is changed, and then you change the data in it again, and again, and again.. this is where the loop starts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a step back and consider what you are semantically telling the code to do.  `useEffect` basically means, "Perform this operation whenever this dependency has changed."

What is the operation in your case?

- Populate the `data` state value.

And what is the dependency?

- The `data` state value.

So you're telling the code to populate `data` (an operation which by definition changes `data`) any time `data` has changed.

Why?

Since the only dependency is `data` then it sounds like you just want this to happen *once* when the component is first mounted.  For that you would use an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your operation
}, []);
```

After that, any time `data` has changed then why are you re-fetching `data`?  Your local copy has changed.  Do you not want to retain those changes?  Did you also change the data on the server and want to completely refresh everything?  In either event, this isn't the approach you'd want to use.

Most likely, whichever operation modified the source of `data` on the server should return the updated data and the client-side code which invoked that operation can then update `data` with that returned value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I know what you mean and have tried already but the reason that i'm updating my "data" is useEffect is the only place that i can upload my code. Because "PersonService" (class) i use fetch to get my json data. I tried to make export "data" variable to update into PersonService class but i couldn't make it.

Comment: @sametyıldızeli: I'm afraid that description doesn't really clear anything up.  Do you mean that `PersonService` contains an operation which updates the data but doesn't return the updated data from the server?  If that's the case then I'd recommend modifying `PersonService` to do that.  Or perhaps in your own code where you invoke that update operation, immediately following it with a fetch operation.  But if `useEffect` really is, as you say, the *only place* where you are allowed to modify code then you're being severely limited by whoever placed that restriction on you.

Comment: const URL = 'http://localhost'; 
class PersonService {
    
    getAllPersonList() {
        return fetch(`${URL}/api/Person`)
        .then(res => res.json());
    }
}
export default new PersonService();

I call this method on the PersonService class.

Comment: @sametyıldızeli: Again, take a step back.  *Why* do you want to re-populate `data` from the server any time `data` changes?

Comment: Because i use this data variable to show in a data table. I'd like to see refreshing the table whenever i add or delete any item on the row. With this code, the code does what i want, which means data is uploaded whenever i make any changes. But with infinitive loop..

Comment: @sametyıldızeli: And what's stopping you from doing that?  The service you show has no operation for updating the server, only fetching data from the server.  So you have the data from the server, and now that data has changed locally.  So you currently have the most updated data locally.  Why do you want to over-write that with stale data from the server?  It sounds like you're either over-thinking something or not thinking about something... Start by solving the problems you already have, not problems you assume you'll have.  When you have modified `data` locally, why can't you display it?

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect is subscribed to '*data*', which you are also updating in the useEffect.

When '*data*' updates, the useEffect runs. Because the useEffect is updating '*data*' you have an infinite loop.

If you want the useEffect to only run once on load, simply remove the data subscription from the useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
   
   PersonService.getAllPersonList()
   .then(res => {
     setData(res)
     console.log(res)
   }
 )
 }, []);
```